# Adding more circles to this plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{3d}
\makeatletter
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother


\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawCoordinateGrid}{O{} m m m m m m}{%
    \def\XGridMin{#2}
    \def\XGridMax{#3}
    \def\YGridMin{#4}
    \def\YGridMax{#5}
    \def\ZGridMin{#6}
    \def\ZGridMax{#7}
    %
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0, thin, red]
      \draw [#1] (\XGridMin,\YGridMin) grid (\XGridMax,\YGridMax);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0, thin, blue]
      \draw [#1] (\YGridMin,\ZGridMin) grid (\YGridMax,\ZGridMax);
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0, thin, orange]
      \draw [#1] (\XGridMin,\ZGridMin) grid (\XGridMax,\ZGridMax);
    \end{scope}
}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawCoordinateAxis}{O{} m m m m m m}{%
    \def\XAxisMin{#2}
    \def\XAxisMax{#3}
    \def\YAxisMin{#4}
    \def\YAxisMax{#5}
    \def\ZAxisMin{#6}
    \def\ZAxisMax{#7}
    %
    \begin{scope}[thin, gray, -latex]
        \draw [#1] (\XAxisMin,0,0) -- (\XAxisMax,0,0) node [below left] {$x$};
        \draw [#1] (0,\YAxisMin,0) -- (0,\YAxisMax,0) node [right] {$y$};
        \draw [#1] (0,0,\ZAxisMin) -- (0,0,\ZAxisMax) node [above] {$z$};
    \end{scope}
}%

% A macro to save repeating the code
\newcommand*{\DrawTriangle}{%
    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
      \draw [fill=yellow!50,opacity=0.6] (0,1) -- (3,0) -- (0,4) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
}%

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) node[below left]{$$}
   -- (0,0) --  (pX,0) node[below left]{$$};
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
    \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (2,0) arc(0:380:1);
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,-1) arc(-90:290:1);
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,0) arc(-90:380:1);


 \end{scope}
 %\foreach \X in {bl,tl,br,tr}
 %{\draw[-latex] (\X1) -- ++ (1,0,0);}
 %
 %\draw (0,0,0) -- (4,0,0);
 % plane
  \fill[gray,fill opacity=0] (-1,-4,0) -- (7,-4,0) --
  (7,4,0) -- (-1,4,0) -- cycle;
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth];

 \end{scope}
 %\draw[-latex] (4,0,0) -- (5.5,0,0) node[below left]{$$};
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0]
   \begin{scope}
      \clip (0,-2) rectangle (4,3);
      \draw[densely dashed] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
      \foreach \X in {0.25,0.75,...,5}
       {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myrnd}{rnd*360}
       \foreach \Y in {-1.75,-1.25,...,1.75}
        {
        %\draw[-stealth] ({\X-0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y-0.2*sin(\myrnd)}) --
        %({\X+0.2*cos(\myrnd)},{\Y+0.2*sin(\myrnd)});
        }
        \draw[densely dashed] (\X+.25,-2) -- (\X+0.25,2);}
   \end{scope}
   %Put here for y rotation! 
  \end{scope}
%
\begin{scope}[shift={($(-4,0,0)-(0,0,0)$)}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,dashed]
   \foreach \X in {2.1,2.3,...,4}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
      %\draw[-latex,thin] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{-2*sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
  % \draw plot[smooth,domain=2:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{-2*sin(\x*180)});  
  \begin{scope}
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
  % \draw[-latex,ultra thin,solid] (12.2,0) -- (12.8,0);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \foreach \X in {2.1,2.3,...,4}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgflowlevelsynccm
     % \draw[-latex,thin] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,{2*sin(\X*180)});
     \end{scope} 
    }
   %\draw plot[smooth,domain=2:4,samples=41] (1*\x,{2*sin(\x*180)});   
 \end{scope} 
 \node at (1*3.5,1.75,0) {$$};
 \node at (1*3.5,0,-1.25) {$$};
\end{scope} 
%
\pgfmathsetseed{42}
\begin{scope}[shift={($(4,0,0)-(0,0,0)$)},
    declare function={amp(\x)=3*exp(-\x)*(0.6+0.8*rnd)*sin(\x*180);}]
 \path (0,0,0) coordinate (B0) coordinate (E0); 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,dashed]
   \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0.2,0.4,...,3}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myamp{-amp(\X)}
      \path (1*\X,\myamp) coordinate(B\Y);
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(abs(\myamp)>0.075,1,0)}
      \ifnum\itest=1
        \pgflowlevelsynccm
        %\draw[-latex,thin] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,\myamp);
      \fi 
      \xdef\Ymax{\Y}
     \end{scope} 
    }
   %\draw plot[smooth,samples at={0,...,\Ymax}] (B\x);  
  \begin{scope}
   \path (4.8,0);
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-latex,ultra thin,solid] (4.2,0) -- (4.8,0);
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope} 
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
   \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0.2,0.4,...,3}
    {\begin{scope}
      \pgfmathsetmacro\myamp{amp(\X)}
      \path (1*\X,\myamp) coordinate(E\Y);
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{ifthenelse(abs(\myamp)>0.075,1,0)}
      \ifnum\itest=1
        \pgflowlevelsynccm
        %\draw[-latex,thin] (1*\X,0) -- (1*\X,\myamp);
      \fi
      \xdef\Ymax{\Y}
     \end{scope} 
    }
  % \draw plot[smooth,samples at={0,...,\Ymax}] (E\x);   
 \end{scope} 
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which outputs the following image [image] and I've been trying to change it with no luck. I want to make every dashed line in the plane contain circles like I have at the origin, with varying radii. Could someone help my code please!

Comment: Your profile says you are a postdoctoral fellow. Shouldn't you then link to the sources of your code pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This adds those circles. Your code has many unnecessary pieces. It would be great if you added links the sources of your code pieces.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
% \makeatletter % only necessary for very old installations
% \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
%   \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
%   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
%   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
%   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
% }
% \makeatother


\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;},
pics/circles/.style={code={
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (2,0) arc(0:380:1);
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,-1) arc(-90:290:1);
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,0) arc(-90:380:1);
}}]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) -- (0,0) --  (pX,0);
   \pic[transform shape]{circles};
   \draw[densely dashed,very thin] (-pX,0) -- (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[densely dashed] foreach \X in {1,...,7}
 { (\X/2,-pX,0) -- coordinate (p\X) (\X/2,pX,0)};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \path foreach  \X in {1,...,7} 
    {(p\X) pic[transform shape]{circles}};
   \pic[transform shape]{circles};
   \draw[densely dashed,very thin] (-pX,0) -- (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

For varying radii you can use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
% \makeatletter % only necessary for very old installations
% \tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
%   \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
%   \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
%   \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
%   \tikz@canvas@is@plane
% }
% \makeatother


\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{20}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,
declare function={pX=2;},
pics/circles/.style={code={
   \pgflowlevelsynccm
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (2,0) arc(0:380:#1);
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,-1) arc(-90:290:#1);
   \draw[-{Latex[bend]}] (0,0) arc(-90:380:#1);
}},pics/circles/.default=1]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0]
 \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl1) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br1)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr1)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl1) -- cycle;
   \draw[stealth-stealth] (0,pX) -- (0,0) --  (pX,0);
   \pic[transform shape]{circles};
   \draw[densely dashed,very thin] (-pX,0) -- (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
 \draw[densely dashed] foreach \X in {1,...,7}
 { (\X/2,-pX,0) -- coordinate (p\X) (\X/2,pX,0)};
 \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=4]
  \draw (-pX,-pX) coordinate (bl2) -- (pX,-pX) coordinate (br2)
   -- (pX,pX) coordinate (tr2)  -- (-pX,pX) coordinate (tl2) -- cycle;
   \foreach  \X in {1,...,7} 
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{1-1/(10-\X)}
    \path(p\X) pic[transform shape]{circles=\myradius};}
   \pic[transform shape]{circles={0.5}};
   \draw[densely dashed,very thin] (-pX,0) -- (pX,0);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The variation is encoded in `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myradius}{1-1/(10-\X)}`. I do not know what you had in mind.

[image]